# Maximum number of attributes a node has in a XML document

Tags: c#, xml, max

We are interested in finding maximum number of attributes a node has in a XML document. My code is below using C#:

```
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(@"C:\ABC.xml");
        XmlNode root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;

        int nodeAttrCount = 0;
        foreach (XmlNode node in root)                            
            if (nodeAttrCount < node.Attributes.Count)
                nodeAttrCount = node.Attributes.Count;
```

We are interested is: do we have any thing better than this. Like any method or property which give us the same result or anyother option.

Comment: [Insert comment about using LINQ with .Max(n => n.Attributes.Count)] [Insert reply comment saying that LINQ is overkill]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use LINQ to XML:

```
XElement el = XElement.Load("MyXML.xml");
int maxAttr = el.DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<XElement>().Max(x => x.Attributes().Count());
```

The above code traverses all the xml nodes (it works with nested nodes too) and get the maximum number of attributes.

---

For .net 2.0:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("MyXML.xml");
int max = 0;
foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in doc.SelectNodes("//*"))
   if (max < node.Attributes.Count)
       max = node.Attributes.Count;
```

This is basically the same as your solution;
the main difference is that it considers all nodes at every nesting level (using XPath navigation).

Comment: Thanks for the code but not working. Gives error '>' as invalid expression. Not recognizing "Max(x => x.Attributes().Count()".

Comment: Mmh really strange, I have just tested the same code and it works fine (I'm targeting .NET 3.5). Do you have "using System.Linq;" in your class header ?

Comment: Thanks but our production server is still running .Net 2.0 :(

Comment: OK, since you select mine as the accepted answer, I've added a solution compatible with .net 2.0. ;)

Comment: Thanks. Although Tim helped me a lot but I was looking for a solution that is elegent and uptodate. I know that there must be some latest solution out there as age of "loop / traverse manually" :) is over. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

This is three lines of code for a fairly niche requirement. I wouldn't expect this to already exist in the .NET framework.

Your `foreach` loop looks fine. Are you sure you want to only look at the root elements, and not recurse inside the document?

Comment: We don't need to go recurse inside the document. In fact our XML is like this:

<root>
<file attrib1="" attrib2="" attrib3="" attrib4="" ... />
.
.
.
.
.
</root>

sounds Ok?